# How to position button to bottomright of table when width is auto?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have included my plunker link here https://plnkr.co/edit/TD6iQJvIExwTeJ9QPbRS?p=preview

I want the submit button to appear at the right bottom of the table.My table width changes according to the data. My table's width is auto. So how will i position the button to right bottom everytime.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table" style="width:auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please accept an answer on your questions so others know the issue is solved

Comment: @ZimSystem I've accepted.Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

When trying remove last tr from tbody and check the width and button position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table" style="width:auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July jan</td>
        <td>Dooley Hello</td>
        <td>julyjan12345678@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right"><button class="btn btn-success pull-right">SUBMIT</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also remove align="right" as it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Grid class to `col-sm-12` and make the width of the table to 100%.
Added the Preview,
https://plnkr.co/edit/M3p2bpj460niGCu59irR?p=preview